# Importing files in UTF-8 and UTF-8 BOM

Tags: encoding, utf-8, doxygen

I am running Doxygen 1.8.11 on a windows machine with a project where there are used special chars like éæøå.

The Doxyfile and some .md files are encoded in UTF-8 and are displayed correctly, but the .cs files are encoded in UTF-8 BOM, special characters in those files gets garbled up.

Is there a way around this without messing with the UTF-8 BOM files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer turned out to be simpler than expected.

I just had to set the INPUT_ENCODING to "iso-8859-1" in my doxyfile

```
INPUT_ENCODING         = iso-8859-1
```